# css border corner overlay

Tags: css, border

There is a way to solve a css border when you use different sizes for left and bottom for example? like that:

[image: Border css overlay]

I know that's angled but but there is a way to use some kind of clipping or mask or even z index on that ?

my css:

```
.activity-container{
  border-bottom: 1px solid @color-border-light;
  border-left: 5px solid @color-green;
  position: relative;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing any example code it is hard to tell what is going on and impossible to help. The question now is way too broad to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index` property does not apply to `border` values, and all `border` sides extend into the element that they are applied to.  I'd suggest `outline` if you wanted a border that extends outside the element, but `outline` can't be applied to individual sides, so it has to be consistent around the element.

All that said, you could use `box-shadow` to act as a psuedo-border on the left side of your element since it can be applied in a way that either extends outside or inside the element (outside by default):

```css
.bordered {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 0px 0px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered"></div>
```

What I'm doing is hiding the left side of the `border` and replacing it with a `box-shadow` that extends outside the left of the element.  Since the `border` extends to the inside and `box-shadow` is extending outward, they meet rather than overlap.

Comment: And what you need the same with both left and right border?